# Is there an Autos and Locals debug function for VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio has the functions Autos and Locals to watch variables. In VS Code I use at the moment only Watch function. I haven't seen the Autos and Locals functions for VS Code; are they not implemented (yet)? And if not implemented; any equivalent solutions? Watch is a bit manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, 
here's the official take on that:
**Data inspection**
Variables can be inspected in the VARIABLES section of the Run view or by hovering over their source in the editor.\ Variable values and expression evaluation are relative to the selected stack frame in the CALL STACK section.
Variable values can be modified with the Set Value action from the variable's context menu.
[image]

Variables and expressions can also be evaluated and watched in the Run view's WATCH section.

[image]

Variable names and values can be filtered by typing while the focus is on the VARIABLES section[image]

**Refrences:** https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_data-inspection